# changing the applications taskbar icon

Tags: ubuntu-mate, sublime-text

Is it possible to change the icon showned in taskbar for an application?

The application is Sublime Text 2.
Sublime is showing a **default** icon, I want a **sublime** icon.

Slack has the same issue:

I installed using:
`sudo snap install slack --classic`

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS - Mate - 64 Bits.

Where the applications icons are configured to be showned in taskbar?

Is there a place on file system? Is it configured by application code itself?

[image]

Comment: How did you install Sublime Text? Is there a specific reason why you're using an outdated version? Sublime Text 2 has been superseded 6 years ago!

Comment: @idleberg, you are right, I'll stop using it, and replace by version 3. but I have the same issue with other applications.

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: @Pablo, unfortunately not.